# MySQL pagination for items from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, pagination, sphinx

There is a page containing diverse items from different MySQL tables (news, articles, video, audio, ...), binded to a certain tag (e.g. "economics").

At the moment, from each table 100 rows binded to the tag are fetched and then grouped and sorted.

I need to introduce a pagination to the page, which is pain in such a situation, because one needs collect all items together in order to get the chunk from some offset with some limit length.

I think I need aggregate items from each table in one data source, and then perform querying (filter by tag) and sort (by date) on it.

What can I use for this purpose? I consider Sphinx search engine, but I'm not sure whether it's good in this case or not - I need only querying and sorting, not full-text search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sphinx is very good solution for your case. You can define one index for all types of your content (news, articles, video, audio), just add field "source_type" which show source table, for example 1 - news, 2 - audio, 3 - video, etc. And add all fields which you want use for filtration.

If you want to search all audio with tag "rock", you just need do filter by "tag" and "source_type" fields. Sphinx do it much more faster than MySQL, particularly if you have very big amount of data. Sphinx will return you only bunch of founded rows (it depends on max_results in sphinx config).

At the same time sphinx easily return you count off all matches very fast. Using LIMIT and OFFSET in your queries to Sphinx you can do pagination.

In that manner you can fetch ids of objects in MySQL db from Sphinx and after that fetch all required data from MySQL.

I used that scenario in the same situation. And it provide great efficiency.

Comment: Eugene Soldatov, as I understand Sphinx filters by some fields ("tag" and "source_type" in your example) much more faster than MySQL do. Is it also true in case these fields have indexes? Just in case, if you have any information about such a comparison, please share it.

Comment: From my experience, it's faster. Particularly sphinx do it best when you need to count all matches with many filters, maybe with some aggregation (for pagination). Unfortunately, I can't provide any benchmarks. I used that scheme in backend for the news mobile app. It had about 1k QPS on one instance of Sphinx and two instances of MySQL. Data amount was something about 500к rows.

Comment: Sphinx doesnt have the concept of 'indexes' like a database would, its completely different setup. In essence ALL the data is a big index - structed in a way to make answering queries fast. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index